# How to interpret comma-comma-at in Common Lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Edit: In my examples, `=>` means "evaluates to", and `->` means "expands to under `macroexpand-1`".

I'm trying to wrap my head around nested back-quoting in Common Lisp, and I think I'm very close to understanding it, thanks to several other SO questions (please don't refer me to them--I've seen them). There's just one last thing that's nagging me. Consider:

```
`(a `(b ,,@(list 'c 'd)))

=> (a `(b ,c ,d))
```

Following the algorithm for expanding back-quoted forms in CLHS, I stepped through the (read-time) expansion process of the first form above, and indeed, evaluating the form obtained from that expansion does give an equivalent result. Now, consider the definition of `once-only` given by Peter Seibel in his excellent book.

```
(defmacro once-only ((&rest names) &body body)
  (let ((gensyms (loop for n in names collect (gensym))))
    `(let (,@(loop for g in gensyms collect `(,g (gensym))))
      `(let (,,@(loop for g in gensyms for n in names collect ``(,,g ,,n)))
        ,(let (,@(loop for n in names for g in gensyms collect `(,n ,g)))
           ,@body)))))
```

Given that definition, SBCL shows the following macro expansion:

```
(once-only (from to)
  `(do ((,var ,from (next-prime (+ 1 ,var))))
       ((>= ,var ,to))
     ,@body)))

-> (LET ((#:G939 (GENSYM)) (#:G940 (GENSYM)))
     `(LET ((,#:G939 ,FROM) (,#:G940 ,TO))
       ,(LET ((FROM #:G939) (TO #:G940))
         `(DO ((,VAR ,FROM (NEXT-PRIME (+ ,1 ,VAR)))) ((>= ,VAR ,TO)) ,@BODY))))
```

Now, my issue is with the second line of the expanded form. Shouldn't it be:

```
`(LET (,(,#:G939 ,FROM) ,(,#:G940 ,TO))
```

?

See how the evaluation of the `,,@` in the first example above ends up "distributing" the comma to the elements spliced from the list `(c d)`? Why doesn't that occur here? The two examples seem to share the same structure, but their evaluated results seem inconsistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see my error. The second line in the macro-expansion above should actually be:

```
`(LET (,`(,#:G939 ,FROM) ,`(,#:G940 ,TO))
```

which is equivalent to what SBCL shows.